# looking for the title of a book regarding slacker who gets a job working with gm pigs

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I've been racking my brain trying to remember the title of a book I read years ago about a dystopian pre-future (society hasn't totally fallen but it's on the way) boy who failed an aptitude test and his mother was able to get him a job working with GMO pigs. There was some conspiracy with the corporation the boy figured out.

All that I can remember is the part about the smart pigs and that that boy's name was Wade.

I thought it was Pig but that brought up nothing.

Comment: Tell us he part you remember about the smart pigs. How smart are they? Do they solve crossword puzzles, play chess, compose symphonies?

Comment: Probably not *Oryx and Crake*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oryx_and_Crake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Everything but the squeal](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Everything-but-Squeal-John-Scalzi-ebook/dp/B01LYVRSB7) by John Scalzi. Surprisingly this doesn't seem to be on IFSDB.

The plot summary given on the Amazon page should clinch it, but for completeness I'll give some details here.

It's in a future high tech but somewhat dystopian America. Benjamin Washington is the ne'er do well son of a senior politician. He has to get a job or be kicked out of the community, but since he did badly in his exams the only job he can get is looking after genetically modified pigs.

The conspiracy is an attempt by people living in the wild outside the community to attack it and steal its genetic technology. Benji foils the attack with the aid of the pigs. It involves a lot of pig, erm, *manure* and some enterprising if unconventional use of porcine mating pheromones.

In the end:

> It ends happily when the community agree to freely share their genetic technology with the outsiders.

The story has been recently reprinted but I think it was first published in 2009. It's a novella rather than a novel as it's only 53 pages.

The only mismatch with your description is that there is no character called Wade.

Comment: JOHN - YOU ROCK!!! YES!!!!! OMG!! Thank you so much!! It was seriously driving me crazy!